MariaDB LIKE with Escape Character - Unexpected Behavior
I'm working on a Laravel application with a jobs table containing job data in the payload column. The payload is a JSON string similar to this:
{"displayName":"App\\Jobs\\V1\\ProcessOrdersPendingCourier"}

I want to fetch records where the displayName key in the JSON payload has the value "App\\Jobs\\V1\\ProcessOrdersPendingCourier". Logically, I used this query:
SELECT * FROM `jobs`
WHERE `payload`
  LIKE '%"displayName":"App\\\\Jobs\\\\V1\\\\ProcessOrdersPendingCourier"%';

However, this query returns no results! After struggling for a while, I discovered that adding ESCAPE '#' to the query magically fetches the expected rows:
SELECT * FROM `jobs`
WHERE `payload`
  LIKE '%"displayName":"App\\\\Jobs\\\\V1\\\\ProcessOrdersPendingCourier"%' ESCAPE '#';

My questions are:

Why does the first LIKE query not work as expected?
Why is the ESCAPE character necessary in this case?

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated!

Notes:
The # in escape '#' can be replaced with other characters like @ or & to act as the escape character. However, using \\ (backslash) as the escape character won't work in this scenario.

ESCAPE is pretty clear in the official documentation for the LIKE keyword for which is it associated. Improvements welcome. Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the problem?  Might be a bug (but couldn't see an existing bug report).

@danblack Thank you for sharing the link to the official documentation for ESCAPE. I’ve created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

if you are looking for a substring, use locate or instr.  only use like if you need its wildcards.  escaping strings for like is more trouble than it is worth; in my testing the following characters needed special treatment [%_\\\0\n\r\x1a\xc2-\xf7]
but better yet, don't treat json as a string, use json_value(...) = ...

One level of backslashes is removed by the parser (unless sql_mode=NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES is given) when scanning string literals from the query.
Another level of backslashes is removed by the LIKE itself (no matter what sql_mode is).
So to match you need to go 4x \ for every real one with a LIKE.

Thank you for your response. You’re absolutely correct. According to the documentation, the backslashes in a LIKE clause serve a dual purpose: they encode special characters like newlines and backslashes themselves when the string is parsed, and they also escape wildcards. This explains why using characters other than \ in the ESCAPE clause would result in matching (because when alternative escape characters are used, the backslashes are treated literally, and in accordance with your 4x rule, they rationally match).

(Without ESCAPE) The number of backslashes (\) you need depends on the number of layers of software (app, connector, etc) it has to go through.  Each layer will turn \\ into \.  When the SQL finally gets it there probably needs there to be 1 backslash.  So, try with 1, 2, 4, 8 to see what works.
(With ESCAPE '#'), then that replaces some, but not all of the backslashes.  Play around until you get ir right.  #\ or #\\ or I don't know what.
Further, be aware that "fiddle" is one of those "layers".  So whatever works there may not work in your code.
